# Global variable, visible only inside the module

Tags: 7

I have several modules, that implement very close functionality. And the SQL requests are almost the same, except for the table name. So I wanted to create a global variable, inside each module:

```
$GLOBALS['module_name'] = __FILE__;
$regexp = "/.*" . "\\" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '(.*)\.module/';
$GLOBALS['module_name'] = preg_replace($regexp, '$1', $GLOBALS['module_name']);
```

$GLOBALS['module_name'] will contain the current file name, which is the same as name of the table.

And then use it in the requests:

```
$query = db_select($GLOBALS['module_name']);
```

But global variables are shared among the modules, and the definition from a different module rewrites the correct value.

I tried to use hook_init

```
function my_module_init()
{
   $GLOBALS['module_name'] = __FILE__;
   $regexp = "/.*" . "\\" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '(.*)\.module/';
   $GLOBALS['module_name'] = preg_replace($regexp, '$1', $GLOBALS['module_name']);
}
```

But without success.

Is it possible to have global variables with the same name in many modules, but each will be visible only inside the appropriate module?

Comment: you can use different names for the global variables inside each module, and can use it differently from the respective module. Even if it is visible to other modules, if it is not called it won't affect anything.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. But in this case I'll have to change name in all the places, where it is used. But the trick was to use the same variable name to change the code as little as possible.

Comment: If Global variable holds FILE name why not use __FILE__ instead every where ? Whats the need to use GLOBAL var ? Or you can define CONSTANTS inside each file that has the actual Table name so in future if you decide to rename table/file it will be of less trouble.

Comment: I didn't know about FILE variable. It can be used for this task. Can you give an example of defining CONSTANTS with the same name, but different values in multiple files, so the value will be visible only inside the appropriate file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the same global variable, its value is shared between all the enabled modules because global variables are globals by definition. Every PHP file that is loaded will see the same global variables, such as the global `$user` that is used from Drupal for the account of the currently logged-in user.

The same is true if you use constants defined with `define()`; they are global, and two modules cannot define the same constants. Try defining the `REQUEST_TIME` in Drupal 7, with `define('REQUEST_TIME, 'test')`: You will get an error, as the same constant is already defined from Drupal (see [REQUEST_TIME](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/REQUEST_TIME/7)).

The same is true for Drupal variables defined with [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7). Every module that is using `variable_set($name, $value)` (where `$name` has the same value for all the modules) is setting the same variable.

Even if you would be using [&drupal_static($name, $value)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) in different modules, the modules will be altering the same static variable.

I would rather use a constant defined with `define()`, but every module needs to use a different constant.
See the [Drupal coding standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards) about [naming conventions](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#naming).

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use `variable` ? `variables` is good feature in drupal and working wth them is safe and easy.

variable_set('module_name',**FILE**);
[variable_set Doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)

and those variable provide everywhere you want just need get them

variable_get($name, $default = NULL);

[variable_get Doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)

I suggest you use `variabled` instead global variables.

Comment: Because in principle, there is no difference. If I set the value to the same variable in different modules, it's value will be overwritten by every module. And I wanted to use many variables with the same name, that will be visible only inside the appropriate module.